# Syntactical sugar method in golang like Ruby

Tags: ruby, go

We have `*` in `ruby`, if we used it with `string` like

```
"a" * 3
 => "aaa"
```

it will generate the string with the multiplier length.

I want to do same in `Go` but couldn't get success.
I am trying to ignore to make a custom method as I need a random string with specified length in `testing`.

Anyone knows about it?

Thanks

I have tried to go through some documents but did not get any short hand method and I am trying to avoid writing a function.

In ruby:

```
"a" * 3
 => "aaa"
```

Comment: [strings.Repeat](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Repeat), [bytes.Repeat](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Repeat). Obviously those don't generate random strings.

Comment: "couldn't get success" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Repeat

From the godoc:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("ba" + strings.Repeat("na", 2))
}
// banana
```